How to fix kicad install having packages unmet dependencies?
I'm trying to install the Kicad v7.0 but was wondering maybe my Chromebook cannot keep-up the good work so I changed into Kicad v6.0 using the repositor of the kicad6. It has problems of dist and I've handled it already by changing the bookworm into jammy but something's still struggling me: this unmet dependencies still struggling me. How could I fix this please help me.enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

We currently don't know what OS/release you're using thus are limited in what help we can provided, however your details ("bookworm into jammy) imply this is a self-inflicted problem anyway related to what you've done.
